# html and css, make header image stay the same size on resize/zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, header

I hope somebody can help me out. 
I'm trying to create a website with a big header image, which always has the same size, no matter how much you would zoom in or out. An example of what I want is this site:

http://www.schalkbelastingexpert.nl/

I would prefer to get this effect without using any javascript/jquery. Of course if needed, I can implement a javascript/jquery solution.

This is the HTML structure of my document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/MainStylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="wrapperMain">
         <header>
            <div id="headerLogo">
 
            </div>
            <nav id="mainNav">
 
            </nav>
            <div id="headerImage">
              <img src="../Media/headerTest.jpg"/>
            </div>
         </header>
        <div id="mainContent">
            someContent
        </div>
        <footer>
 
        </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a background image for the header. If you are leaving it empty put a min-height.

Comment: I did do that, but it doesn't exactly give what I want. It will cut of the image on resize. As you can see in the example the image will always stay the same size on resize, it won't cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Use an image that has similar proportion as the banner size and the image will not be so much cut of. In the example you provided there is a script that adjust the height of the banner. For this you should just go with a pure css solution.

```
#headerImage {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(imageUrl);
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

Note. CSS classes are better than id's for styling.

http://codepen.io/ingvijonasson/pen/KwejKo

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question, because the image will resize itself when I resize the window. I wanted it to stay the same size like in the example